# VBA Excel Error91 - Object Variable not found - PowerPoint Automation - Simple Mistake?

Tags: excel, vba, object, powerpoint

Im relatively new to VBA and am trying to find the cause for this one error for hours now. I really need help :P

I have an Excel Macro that automatically creates a PowerPoint and copys Shapes from Excel to PP. So far so good. Now Im trying to add Textboxes as Shapes to PP, which works for the 1st box but throws errors for the second textbox on the next slide.
The main method creates the PP and then calls Subs to insert different textboxes from another module

The Code is like this:

```
Sub mainmethod()
Public Shape As Object
Public PPshape As PowerPoint.Shape
Public PPapp As PowerPoint.Application
Public PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Public PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Public rng As Range
Public PPdateipfad As String
Public maturitylevel As String
Public PPtextbox_1 As PowerPoint.Shape
...
Set PPslide = PPapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Duplicate.Item(1)
Call Textbox_1(PPslide)
Call Textbox_2(PPslide)
...
```

```
Sub Textbox_1(ByVal PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide)

Set PPtextbox_1 = PPslide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=167, Top:=460, Width:=625, Height:=25)

With PPtextbox_1.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = "textbox1"

End With
End Sub
```

```
Sub Textbox_2(ByVal PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide)

Set PPtextbox_2 = PPslide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=167, Top:=460, Width:=625, Height:=25)

With PPtextbox_2.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = "textbox2"

End With
End Sub
```

Now sometimes this works for textbox1 and only throws an error for textbox2. Sometimes it only works for textbox1 but always throws an error for textbox2.

The error is "Object variable or With block variable not Set" on the Line:

Set PPtextbox_1 = PPslide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=167, Top:=460, Width:=625, Height:=25)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `PPslide` is not `Set`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought about this, too. But where do I have to set it? Cause it is set in the main method. Do I have to set it again in the Textbox-Sub? I thought if its public it takes it from the main method. Thank you so much for your answer. I already tried "Set PPslide = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)" in the textbox sub but it did not work..

Comment: This is the danger of using `Public` variables. I would add an argument: `Sub Textbox_1(ByVal PPslide As Powerpoint.Slide)`.

Comment: I did this and now it says "Compile Error: Argument not optional" in the main method where it calls Subtext1()

Sorry to waste your time by being a VBA noob but I reaaaaally appreciate your help

Comment: Change `Call Textbox_1()` to `TextBox_1 PPslide`, or `Call Textbox_1(PPslide)` if you prefer to use `Call`.

Comment: I did. Now it throws the same error as originally in the Textbox1-Sub on the same line (Set PPtextbox_1 = PPslide.Shapes...)

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with your revised code, including where you `Set PPslide` in the main sub.

Comment: Done. PPslide set through creating a new slide (second slide is my master layout slide, so it copies it and puts at the end of the presentation)
I also added "Public PPtextbox1 As PowerPoint.Shape" to main method cause thats where all my declarations are, hope thats correct.

Comment: any more tips? can't figure it out

Comment: Right before `Call Textbox_1(PPslide)`, put `Debug.Print PPslide Is Nothing` and check the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: When I run the code with that line right infront, it still throws the same error as before, nothing new appears.

Comment: Now it at leasted worked for Textbox_1 but that randomly worked before as well so probably nothing changed :/

Comment: Hit Ctrl+G and check the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: My bad, im dumb. The output is:
False
False
True
False
True
False
True

Comment: That means that something in your main sub is causing `PPslide` to become `Nothing`.

Comment: I love you man <3 That was exactly it, works like intended now. God bless your helpful soul